# Why is the Bitmap object returning a value in one call and null in another?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, nullpointerexception

I have a Bitmap object that displays perfectly fine when called by ImageView **imgView**'s *setImageBitmap()* method, but when I call it through method *steg()* ..which has a Bitmap argument and uses said argument to pass through another method. The same Bitmap object is accessed in the method for its *getWidth()* value, but this time it returns null as explained by a NullPointerException in my LogCat. However, I don't understand how this could be so if it has a value for the *setImageBitmap()* method.

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

// Get the cursor
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
   filePathColumn, null, null, null);
// Move to first row
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();

opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inDither = false;
opt.inScaled = false;
opt.inDensity = 0;
opt.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
opt.inPurgeable = false;
opt.inSampleSize = 1;
opt.inScreenDensity = 0;
opt.inTargetDensity = 0;

Bitmap covBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString, opt);

// Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
imgView.setImageBitmap(covBitmap);//Returns the pic fine`
```

But, when I pass the same Bitmap object (through a class and a method) to another method which contains the line below, my LogCat states that the object is null at the following line but it can't be null if it returned a value in the above *setImageBitmap()*. Btw, bm is the same Bitmap object renamed when passed to the new class.

```
bm.getWidth();//LogCat says this line can't run bc it there is a null object.
```

The Bitmap object gets passed cleanly through both methods and between the classes.

```
public Uri encode(Bitmap covering, String msg, Context context, String title) {
   //the Bitmap argument is fine

    final Runnable mIncrementProgress = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("mIncrement Runnable HERE");
        }
    };
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Uri result=null;
    String s = msg;//String to be encoded

    int width = covering.getWidth();//If this line gets deleted of course
    int height = covering.getHeight();//this line throws the same error

    int[] oneD = new int[width * height];
    covering.getPixels(oneD, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    int density = covering.getDensity();
    covering.recycle();
    byte[] byteImage = LSB2bit.encodeMessage(oneD, width, height, s,
            new ProgressHandler() {
                private int mysize;
                private int actualSize;`
```

These line snippets show how the object is passed.

```
String filePath = new Cover().imgDecodableString;
BitmapFactory.Options bmfo = new Cover().opt;

    //all items below are in onCreate() method except more method steg()
    bmfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmfo.inDither = false;
    bmfo.inScaled = false;
    bmfo.inDensity = 0;
    bmfo.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmfo.inPurgeable = false;
    bmfo.inSampleSize = 1;
    bmfo.inScreenDensity = 0;
    bmfo.inTargetDensity = 0;

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, bmfo);
    steg(bm);

public void steg(Bitmap cover) {//this method is not in the onCreate() of course
        encode.encode(cover, "MESSAGE", context, title);
}
```

Thank you in advance to you all!

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the code related to `bm.getWidth();`? i.e. how you created this `bm` object, or passed in through some method..

Comment: @Gosu    I've just added some code to allow you to see the transference of the Bitmap object through the class and methods.

Comment: You have this comment that says "the Bitmap argument is fine" in your `encode` function. I do not know what you mean by that, but can you add a `if(covering != null) // print something` at the start of the function and right before you call `getWidth()`?

Comment: If covering is in fact not null, getWidth() shouldn't throw a NullPointerException

Comment: @Gosu covering is the same object as "covBitmap"  and is therefore not null.  That is the problem

Comment: Did you test if it's not null within the encode function??

Comment: Yes it is null in the encode function, because that is the one that contains my getWidth() call.  @Gosu

Comment: `Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, bmfo);` isn't working imo, why are you getting filePath and bmfo from `new Cover()`? Print out `filePath` and see if it's a valid value? `cov` is not retrieved in the exact same manner as `bm`, so I doubt that they are really the same.

Comment: Because in class Cover() an image is displayed to the user(hence setImageBitmap())  but in the class containing bmfo and such, I need the same image not to show to the user but for later processing (hence encode())  @Gosu

Comment: You are only giving chunks of your code here and there, it's hard to tell why it's not working. I think your `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, bmfo)` is returning null as `filePath` or `bmfo` aren't exactly correct values.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience and will post the full code later of needed, but filePath and bmfo are exactly the same as imgDecodableString and opt @Gosu